# @Autowired overrides @Bean

Tags: java, spring

I've got a strange problem (or perhaps just some misconception about Spring 4.1.7):

There's a component, let's call it MyComponent that looks like this...

```
@Component
public class MyComponent extends BaseComponent {
...
}
```

BaseComponent is something like this...

```
public class BaseComponent {    
   @Autowired
   private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

   public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
      this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
   }
}
```

While the class is annotated with @Component for historic reasons, component-scanning is not activated for this package, so the Component will not be found automatically. Thus I have a definition in my @Configuration...

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

 @Bean 
 public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate() { ... create one ... }


 @Bean 
 public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplateSecondary() { ... create another one ... }


 @Bean
 public MyComponent myComponent() {
    MyComponent component = new MyComponent();
    component.setHibernateTemplate( hibernateTemplateSecondary() );
    return component;
 } 
}
```

Unfortunately, what now happens is, that myComponent will be initialized first correctly with the secondary `HibernateTemplate`, but afterwards, Spring injects the "**normal**" `hibernateTemplate` into it (which is wrong).

I've tried to explicitly add `autowire = Autowire.NO` to the @Bean definition, even if that's already the default... Also there aren't two myComponent beans, it's always the same one...

Has anyone an idea why this happens and if so, how to prevent it? I always thought that when @Bean is involved, @Autowired will not overwrite that?

Please note: Because `MyComponent` is used in other projects as well, I absolutely cannot touch it. I cannot remove the `@Autowired` and I cannot add a `@Qualifier` or similar, because that would break a lot of other projects. Normally, it works fine, since it used the "primary" (and normally, only) database connection. Just in this module, another database should be the primary one and thus `MyComponents` needs to be told to use the secondary one.

Comment: Why not simply remove the `@Autowired`?

Comment: Can't do that, since `MyComponent` is used in a lot of other modules where it is component-scanned. Just in this module, it should not be (since this module uses a different "primary" database).

Comment: To understand your problem, first time hibernateTemplate variable in BaseComponent wired with hibernateTemplate object from hibernateTemplateSecondary() method and later the same hibernateTemplate  variable is overwrite the initial one with hibernateTemplate from hibernateTemplate()  method. Is this your point right?

Comment: Correct. First time, in my `@Bean` method, I initialize the `MyComponent` correctly with the `hibernateTemplate` from `hibernateTemplateSecondary()`, but afterwards, Spring decides that it should also `@Autowire` it and thus replaced the `hibernateTemplate` I set with the one from `hibernateTemplate()`.

Comment: Change your configuration class to create single HibernateTemplate object based on condition. In your case single method which returns hibernateTemplate object. Inside the method you can put condition on which HibernateTemplate object to be created. If this is not going to work out you can go for @conditional annotation.

Comment: Since some beans need the original hibernate template, and some beans need the secondary, I need to actually create both, so I don't see how a condition would help, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use @Qualifier("hibernateTemplateSecondary") in the BaseComponent so it can pick up the right bean?

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("hibernateTemplateSecondary")
private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
```

Another approach is to use primary annotation which doesn't look good in your case (taking into account that it's your secondary bean)

```
@Bean 
@Primary
public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplateSecondary() { ... create another one ... }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot touch `MyComponent`. I know this would solve the problem, no doubt, and it would actually be my prefered approach, too, but it is used in multiple other modules (and there, component-scanning is used).

Answer (score 1):

maybe there's a better solution, but you could solve this with a BeanPostProcessor like this:

```
@Component
public class MyBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("hibernateTemplateSecondary")
  private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplateSecondary;

  @Override
  public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    return bean;
  }

  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if (bean instanceof MyComponent) {
      ((MyComponent) bean).setHibernateTemplate(hibernateTemplateSecondary);
    }
    return bean;
  }
}
```

This will inject the correct template **after** the bean has been initialized and will overwrite the wrong one.

Comment: This is similar (but slightly better) than what the current workaround is (inject the secondary hibernate template into all beans using the MyComponent and call the setter there again). Thanks. It doesn't solve the problem itself, but it seems to be a more reasonable workaround.

Comment: I also had some success using a custom `InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter` that returns `false` for `postProcessAfterInstantiation` the `MyComponent`, but that's all fighting symptoms, I still don't know WHY it autowires at all. It shouldn't do that, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on your question by googling on this same issue. I solved it this way:
(tested in spring boot 2.0/spring 5.0)

```
@Bean 
public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate() { ... create one ... }

@Bean 
public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplateSecondary() { ... create another one ... }

@Bean
public MyComponent myComponent() {
  // Let Spring do its job
  return new MyComponent();
}

@Bean
public Void tuneMyComponent(MyComponent myComponent,
                            @Qualifier("hibernateTemplateSecondary") HibernateTemplate tpl) {
  // Override whatever you want
  myComponent.setHibernateTemplate(tpl);

  // Not really a Bean
  return null;
}
```